# OpenGL LWJGL3 object in scene will not rotate

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to learn how to use OpenGL with LWJGL3, however, I've fallen short at an early hurdle. I've set up the scene so it renders half an octohedron, with each face having a different colour to be distinguished between. I have this code to create the shape:

```
    private void drawOctohedron() {
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef((float)glfwGetTime() * 60,0f,1f,0f);
    System.out.println(glfwGetTime());
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); {
        glColor4f(1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F);
        glVertex3i(0, 1, 0);
        glVertex3i(-1, 0, 0);
        glVertex3i(0, 0, 1);
        glNormal3i(-1, 1, 1);

        glColor4f(0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F);
        glVertex3i(0, 1, 0);
        glVertex3i(0, 0, 1);
        glVertex3i(1, 0, 0);
        glNormal3i(1, 1, 1);

        glColor4f(0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
        glVertex3i(0, 1, 0);
        glVertex3i(1, 0, 0);
        glVertex3i(0, 0, -1);
        glNormal3i(1, 1, -1);

        glColor4f(1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
        glVertex3i(0, 1, 0);
        glVertex3i(0, 0, -1);
        glVertex3i(-1, 0, 0);
        glNormal3i(-1, 1, -1);
    }
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

and this is the loop:

```
    private void loop() {
    // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
    // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
    // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
    // creates the ContextCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
    // bindings available for use.
    GLContext.createFromCurrent();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    while ( glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_FALSE ) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwPollEvents();

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        glLoadIdentity();

        camera.lookThrough();

        drawOctohedron();

        glFlush();

        System.out.println("UPS: " + 1/(glfwGetTime() - lastTime));

        lastTime = glfwGetTime();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    System.out.println("Closing");

}
```

The shape renders fine to the display but the rotation only occurs once. The method is called every tick and the System.out line is printing a different value every tick. My question being, why is the rotation only happening once and not updating the next time the method is called? I'm probably just being very stupid about one little thing.

Comment: Does this actually display anything? You are missing an important call to `glEnd ()`. You are also setting the vertex normal ***after*** each triangle, that does not make a lot of sense. I would move each call to `glNormal3i(...);` so that it comes immediately after `glColor4f(...);`.

Comment: It was the glEnd I was missing, thanks

Comment: When I commented out the line `camera.lookThrough();` (you provided no information about it), fixed some imports, plugged your code into this minimal example: `http://www.lwjgl.org/guide` and fixed the error Andon M. Coleman mentioned (adding `glEnd()`), the program runs fine. Maybe you try adding `glEnd()` after your block with the Triangles?

Comment: glEnd was the problem I'm now getting some weird results when I rotate it in more than just the y axis